# How to complete "ms crm duplication plugin" without exception and without message?

Tags: c#, sdk, dynamics-crm-2016

I wrote the following plug-in for ms crm 2016 that's detect duplication.

```
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        var serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        var service = (IOrganizationService)serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            var entity = (Entity) context.InputParameters["Target"];
            var name = entity.GetAttributeValue<string>("name");

            var opportunityCompany = new QueryExpression
            {
                EntityName = entity.LogicalName,
                ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("name")
            };
            opportunityCompany.Criteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, name);

            var retrieveAccount = service.RetrieveMultiple(opportunityCompany);

            //If the retrieved Company Count Greater Than 1 , following Error Message Throw

            if (retrieveAccount.Entities.Count > 1)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("Following Record with Same Name is Exists");
            }
        }
    }
```

This works fine but in case of duplicate i want to end record creation  without exception and without message on page. How can i do this in plug-in? Some people talks to me that i can implement this in CodeActivity. How can i implement CodeActivity in ms crm plug-in?

Or rather I want to stop the plug-in so that the "user" did not know about it. How better do it?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to "prevent a record from being created without having the user know about it". The only supported way of preventing a record creation is if a synchronous plugin is registered on `pre-operation` and an exception is thrown. CRM rolls back the entire transaction preventing a save.

A better alternative would be to use **JavaScript**:

On Save of the record, query CRM for the matching records and [Prevent Save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509060.aspx#BKMK_preventDefault) of the record on the client side. This way the save would never even make it to the server side.

---

Ugly workaround (if for whatever reason you prefer not to use JavaScript):

Register the plugin on `post-op` or use a custom workflow activity and delete the record after the fact. Not ideal.